# Error message not showing below the login form when a user unsuccessfully log in

Tags: php, authentication

I'm new to php. I'm trying to add php to my website to check whether the login information matches the one which is stored in my database but for some reason the error message is not appearing below the login form when email address and password doesn't match.
Here's my login form which is account.php:

```
<!--loginform-->
<p style="margin-left:30px; font-size:23px; margin-top:150px; font-family:Gisha;">Login or Create an Account</p>
<hr style="color:#666; width:95%; align:center; margin-top:-21px;">
<div id="center-login">
<table  cellpadding="10px" cellspacing="40px">
  <form id="form1" onSubmit="return validate()" action="checklogin.php" method="post">
    <tr>
      <td width="600px"><p style="font-family:Gisha;  font-size:19px; margin-top:-25px;">New Customers</p>
        <hr style="color:#F8F8F8; width:100%;  margin-top:-5px; "></td>
      <td width="600px"><p style="font-family:Gisha; font-size:19px; margin-top:-25px;">Registered Customers</p>
        <hr style="color:#F8F8F8; width:100%;  margin-top:-5px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p style="font-family:Gisha; font-size:16px; margin-top:-130px;">By creating an account with our store, you will be able to move through the checkout process faster, store multiple shipping addresses, view and track your orders in your account and more.</p>
        <br>
        <span>
        <input class="submit-log" style="padding:7px; background:black; color:white; font-weight:bold; font-size:19px; cursor:pointer;" type="button" value="Create an Account" onClick="window.location='newaccount.html'">
        </span></td>
      <td><p style="font-family:Gisha; font-size:16px; margin-top:-45px">If you have an account with us, please log in.</p>
        <p style="font-family:Gisha; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold;">Email Address</p>
        <p>

          <input type="text" id="username" name="email" class="input"><span id="errorIMG" style="visibility:hidden; margin-top:-5px;"><img src="images/Error.png" width="15" height="15" style=" margin-bottom:-2px;"/> <span id="errorMsg" style="color:#FF0000; font-family:Gisha;"></span></span>
        </p>
        <p style="font-family:Gisha; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold;">Password</p>
        <p>
          <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd"><span id="errorIMG1" style="visibility:hidden; margin-top:-5px;"><img src="images/Error.png" width="15" height="15" style=" margin-bottom:-2px;"/> <span id="errorMsg1" style="color:#FF0000; font-family:Gisha;"></span></span>
        </p>
        <span>
        <input class="submit-log" style="padding:8px; background:black; color:white; font-weight:bold; font-size:19px; cursor:pointer;" type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
        </span>

</table>
</div>
<div id="errorMsg">
<?php
if(isset($_GET['check']))
{
if($_GET['check']=="fail")
{
echo "<font color='red'><b>Wrong email/password combination</b></font>";
}
else
if($_GET['check']=="good")
{
header('Location:90210.html');
}
}
?>
</div>
</form>
<!--end of login form-->
```

This is the checklogin.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

$Email=$_POST['email'];
$Pwd=$_POST['pwd'];

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con){
die('Could not connect:' .mysql_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully.";
$database=mysql_select_db('90210store');
if(!$database){
die('<br>Could not select database:' .mysql_error());
}
echo "<br>Database successfully selected";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login
 WHERE EmailAdd='$Email' AND Password='$Pwd' LIMIT 1") or      die('QueryFailed:'.mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    $ID= $_SESSION['ID']=1234;
    header('Location:verifyuser.php');
    exit();
}


else {
   header('Location:account.php');
   exit();
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

This is verifyuser.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['ID']))
{
echo "<script>alert('Login successful!');</script>";
echo "<script>window.location = '90210.html';</script>";
exit();
}

else
{
header('Location:account.php');
exit();
}
?>
```

Why is it not showing? Please try to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: Show the code in `checklogin.php` - is that file correctly re-directing users to this login page with `?check=fail|good` ?

Comment: Thanks I added the missing codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the cause of this, by reading the symptoms you describe it becomes clear that most likely the variable `$_GET['check']` simply is not set. It might also be that it is just not set in case of a failed login attempt or hold a value different to "good" or "fail". But since you did not post the code for the validation that is something we only can *guess*.

In addition your php code is error prone. I suggest you change it towards this structure:

```
<?php
if (   isset($_GET['check']) {
    && $_GET['check']=="good") ) {
        header('Location:90210.html');
} else {
    echo "<font color='red'><b>Wrong email/password combination</b></font>";
}
?>
```

1. always test for the good case and handle that, treat *everything else* as bad case, that way you automatically handle unexpected cases.
2. you combined two if conditions, but no else. That means if none of the conditions evaluated to true, then *nothing* would happen. That is not what you want.
3. I suggest to combine the two checks (existance and value of that variable) into one single check by using a boolean `AND` operator (`&&`). That way you have a clear distinction: either all is fine, or something is not ok, in which case you most likely will block access. That way your code is much less complex, thus more robust.

Some general remarks:

- you appear to store the users passwords inside the database *in plain text*! That is a very bad style and opens security risks for you and for the user. Instead you should *never* store the real password but only a hash of it. Then during a login attempt you again hash the provided password and *compare the hashes*. That way you prevent a password leak even if your system gets compromised. Also keep in mind for this that a hash is something else than an encryption, you want to use a hash here.
- you are using a deprecated database driver, phps old `mysql` extension. Please consult the excellent documentation about this. You definitely should switch to the more modern and more robust new `mysqli` extension or `PDO` and learn about the advantages of "prepared statements". Your current code is *wide open to sql injections*.

Comment: You are welcome. Please also understand the additional things I pointed out. That is important!